# I'm getting unwanted style for my button, and I cant seem to find how to change it

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

Edit: I'm using React not React Native

I'm working on a project using React. One of my buttons keeps on inheriting a style with a specific font size: 19px and I cant find the source in the code.
I have gone all over the code several times trying to find a corresponding css code that can affect the button.
I tried changing the font sizes as well, none of them being 19px - and still the style for my button has 19px .

This is the button element and it's style I got from chrome Inspect:

```
<button class="Social-smallFont-6" style="display: block; border: 0px;
 border-radius: 3px; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 1px 2px; color:
 rgb(255, 255, 255); cursor: pointer; font-size: 19px; margin: 5px; width:
 calc(100% - 10px); overflow: hidden; padding: 0px 10px; user-select: none;
 height: 50px; background: rgb(203, 63, 34);"><div style="align-items: center;
 display: flex; height: 100%;"><div style="display: flex; justify-content:
 center; min-width: 26px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="26px" height="26px" fill="#ffffff" viewBox="0 0 50 50"></div><div
 style="width: 10px;"></div><div style="text-align: left; width: 100%;">Login
 with Google</div></div></button>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using `!important`? Without seeing more css we can only begin to create hypothesis on this matter. Maybe someone set `font-size: 19px !important;` somewhere else in the code. If you use important on a higher-level definition, it will probably overwrite the previous one.

Comment: what is the CSS class Social-smallFont-6 defining?

Comment: Are you using this code in react or react-native project ?
In react-native you cannot use dom elements (div, button) and most of the style properties that you have dont work! Please check the question and modify

Comment: @Izbernado I used !important and it worked, thanks!

@ Anthony The CSS class Social-smallFont-6, is a the style I'm trying to use, I'm using Material UI and the Higher Component Styling method:[link](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/)

`const styles = theme => ({
    topright: {
        alignSelf: 'flex-start',
        marginTop: 0,
        position: 'absolute', 
    },
    smallFont: {
        fontSize: 12 + 'px !important',
        width: 30 + 'vh !important',
    }
});`

Answer (score 0):

How are you developing an app on react-native and debugging it on chrome?

Seems that you are just using react so here's an answer that might help:

In react, to set the css class, you use the `className` tag instead of `class`.
In react-native you don't set `class` nor `className`, is through the style tag.

You can't pass a string in the `style` tag, you pass an object: `style={{ color: 'white'}}`

Hope this gives you a better understanding on how to set styles.